# ASP .NET MVC 5 - DropDownList com ModelState?

Tags: c#, mvc, dropdownlist

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro utilizando `MVC5` com `DAO`, porém vieram algumas dúvidas que não consegui solucionar.

Tenho uma tabela onde cadastro Projetos e uma outra onde ficam os tipos de Projetos:

***Tabela: Projetos***

*Campos:*

- ProjProjetoId
- ProjNome
- ProjTipoId

***Tabela: ProjetoTipo***

*Campos:*

- ProjTipoId
- ProjTipoNome

Preciso mostrar na minha `view` um `DropDownList` com todos os projetos para o usuário selecionar (no cadastro). E também preciso trazer esses Tipos de Projetos na página de Editar Projeto, de modo que o valor cadastrado anteriormente venha selecionado.

Após algumas pesquisas consegui fazer funcionar, porém não do jeito que eu gostaria que atualmente o código se encontra assim:

**(ProjetoController)**

```
//Controller GET: Projeto/Edit/5
public ActionResult Editar(int id)
{
    //Pesquisar projeto selecionado
    ProjetoDAO proj_dao = new ProjetoDAO();
    Projeto proj = proj_dao.listById(id);

    //Pesquisar todos os TIPOS de projetos
    ProjetoTipoDAO proj_tipo_dao = new ProjetoTipoDAO();
    List<ProjetoTipo> lista_projetotipo = proj_tipo_dao.ListAll();

    //Lista de SelectListItem
    List<SelectListItem> lista_ddl = new List<SelectListItem>();

    //Percorrer lista de Tipos de Projetos e adicionar na lista de SelectListItem
    bool selected = false;
    foreach (var item in lista_projetotipo)
    {
        //Checar se é o ID selecionado
        selected = (proj.ProjTipoId.ToString().Equals(item.ProjTipoId.ToString()));

        //Adicionar item na lista
        lista_ddl.Add(
            new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = item.ProjTipoNome,
                Value = item.ProjTipoId,
                Selected = selected
            });
    }

    //Enviando a lista de Tipos de Projetos para a view através de ViewBag
    ViewBag.ListaTiposProjeto = lista_ddl;
}
```

***(Editar.cshtml)***

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjTipo, 
                 new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ListaTiposProjeto", null, 
              "Selecione um item", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma, consigo exibir os dados no `DropDownList` e também trazê-lo selecionado na página de editar, porém não consigo utilizar o `ModelState` para validar o formulário.

- Como eu faria a mesma coisa usando o `@Html.DropDownListFor<>`?
- Esse seria mesmo o caminho?, pois segui alguns tutoriais e não deram certo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um ViewBag com as informações do TipoProjeto, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
  public ActionResult Editar(int id)
    {
        //Pesquisar projeto selecionado
        ProjetoDAO proj_dao = new ProjetoDAO();
        Projeto proj = proj_dao.listById(id);

        //Pesquisar todos os TIPOS de projetos
        ProjetoTipoDAO proj_tipo_dao = new ProjetoTipoDAO();
        List<ProjetoTipo> lista_projetotipo = proj_tipo_dao.ListAll();

        SelectList dropDown = new SelectList(lista_projetotipo, "ProjTipoId", "ProjTipoNome");

        ViewBag.ListaTiposProjeto = dropDown;

        return View(proj);
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjTipo, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjTipo, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaTiposProjeto, "Selecione um item", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

é necessário que na sua classe Projeto tenha o ID de Tipo de projeto e que na recuperação do objeto esse ID tenha valor

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou da forma como eu precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Na sua viewmodel, crie o seguinte atributo:

```
public SelectList TiposProjeto { get; set; }
```

aí, onde você prepara a sua tela (controller ou alguma outra camada), você populará:

```
model.TiposProjeto = new SelectList(proj_tipo_dao.ListAll(), "ProjTipoId", "ProjTipoNome");
```

no seu arquivo cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjTipoId, Model.TiposProjeto, "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

dessa maneira, caso já tenha valor dentro de `ProjTipoId`, ele já virá selecionado.